# Get the access token in asp net without calling "Token" method

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, facebook-login, access-token

I'm developing a website that can login by social network using Asp.Net WebAPI.
In my website, the client part I use the Facebook Login SDK, follow the instructions in the Facebook site and got the account of my facebook acccount.
The I write a service (Angular service) and call the Server to login my site with the Facebook userID.

```
function loginExternal(LoginProvider, ProviderKey)
    {
        var data = {
            'LoginProvider':LoginProvider,
            'ProviderKey':ProviderKey
        }
        return $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:url,
            data:data
        });
    }
```

In the server, I write a new method in AccountController.cs which will take the request from client, check the account and return the access token of this account.

> //POST api/Account/LoginExternal

```
//POST api/Account/LoginExternal
            [AllowAnonymous]
            [Route("LoginExternal")]
            public async Task<IHttpActionResult> LoginExternal(UserLoginInfoViewModel model)
            {
                ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(new UserLoginInfo(model.LoginProvider,
                   model.ProviderKey));

                bool hasRegistered = user != null;

                if (hasRegistered)//has the account in database
                {
                    Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

                    ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                       OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                    ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

                    AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user);

                    Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);
                }
                else //dont have the account database - not implemented
                {
                }
                return Ok();
            }
```

At this point, I could check whether the account existed in the database. However, I don't know how to return the access_token corresponding to this account in this method? Before, when I want to login a local account, I have to call to server

> localhost:8080/Token

and pass through the account name and password, the response will return access_token. But how can I do with this method?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. Please look at my answer. :)

```
   //POST api/Account/LoginExternal
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("LoginExternal")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> LoginExternal(UserLoginInfoViewModel model)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(new UserLoginInfo(model.LoginProvider,
               model.ProviderKey));

            bool hasRegistered = user != null;

            if (hasRegistered)//has the account in database
            {
                Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

                ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                   OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager,
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

                AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user);
                //Create an access_token with expire time 14 days
                AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, new AuthenticationProperties());
                DateTime currentUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
                ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));
                string accessToken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);

                Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);
                return Ok(accessToken);//Return Access_token to client
            }
            else //dont have the account database - not implemented
            {

            }

        }
```